# PHP array_walk closure does not assign value properly to a given variable

Tags: php, arrays

I have am array containing these elements: id, email, type

I want to remove type and id and preserve email.

I have echoed and print_r the array and the subsequent elements and everything is fine.

But for filtering through the arrays and returning only the list emails, the following code is written, which, however does not work:

```
             $arr = array_walk($final_list, function($var){
                 return $var['email'];                 
           });
```

While if I echo `$var['email']` it echoes the emails accordingly.

Comment: You shouldn't return from the array_walk callback, you pass by reference

Comment: `array_walk` is not the best function to use in this instance. I would suggest you take a look at [`array_column`](http://php.net/array_column).

Comment: would you please come up with an answer, thanks

Comment: Note that array_column() requires PHP 5.5+, unless you use the [userland implementation](https://github.com/ramsey/array_column); but it is the best answer to what you're trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `array_walk` as if it were `array_map`. This would work:

```
$arr = array_map(function($var){ return $var['email']; }, $final_list);
```

On PHP 5.5+ there is also a more convenient way:

```
$arr = array_column($final_list, 'email');
```

Both of the above versions operate non-destructively: they create a copy of the email data from your input array.

*For completeness only*, and in the (unlikely) case that you do not want this because it uses up extra memory and instead prefer to modify your input by removing data from it, `array_walk` is an option:

```
array_walk($final_list, function(&$var){ // by reference!
    unset($var['id']);
    unset($var['type']);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[`array_walk()`](http://php.net/array_walk) is for applying a callback function to all the elements in the array. To filter the array, use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/array_filter) instead.

```
$arr = array_filter($final_list, function ($elem) {
    return $elem == 'email';
});
```

However, if you're using PHP 5.5+, you can use the very handy function `array_column()` to achieve this:

```
$arr = array_column($final_list, 'email');
```

If you're using an older version of PHP and cannot upgrade to PHP 5.5, you may use the Userland implementation of the function (written by the same author who wrote the `array_column()` function for PHP core). The source code is available on [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/ramsey/array_column).